# WIX MSI Upgrade fails on SECUREREPAIR on some domains

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I am having a MSI generated with WIX that either installs or upgrade a product.
It has normally worked fine but it is now failing in a set of computers of a domain.

The part of the log where the error is (note I have changed the paths...):

```
Action start 09:52:42: RegisterProduct.
RegisterProduct: Registering product
MSI (s) (20:28) [09:52:42:999]: Resolving source.
MSI (s) (20:28) [09:52:42:999]: Resolving source to launched-from source.
MSI (s) (20:28) [09:52:42:999]: Setting launched-from source as last-used.
MSI (s) (20:28) [09:52:42:999]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding SourceDir property. Its value is 'path to msi'.
MSI (s) (20:28) [09:52:42:999]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding SOURCEDIR property. Its value is 'path to msi'.
MSI (s) (20:28) [09:52:42:999]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding SourcedirProduct property. Its value is '{969A6191-5768-45DB-A282-337F711B06A3}'.
MSI (s) (20:28) [09:52:42:999]: SOURCEDIR ==> path to msi
MSI (s) (20:28) [09:52:42:999]: SOURCEDIR product ==> {969A6191-5768-45DB-A282-337F711B06A3}
MSI (s) (20:28) [09:52:42:999]: Determining source type
MSI (s) (20:28) [09:52:43:015]: Incrementing counter to disable shutdown. Counter after increment: 0
MSI (s) (20:28) [09:52:43:015]: Source type from package 'software.msi': 6
MSI (s) (20:28) [09:52:43:015]: Decrementing counter to disable shutdown. If counter >= 0, shutdown will be denied.  Counter after decrement: -1
MSI (s) (20:28) [09:52:43:015]: SECREPAIR: Hash Database: C:\Windows\Installer\SourceHash{969A6191-5768-45DB-A282-337F711B06A3}
MSI (s) (20:28) [09:52:43:015]: Machine policy value 'AlwaysInstallElevated' is 0
MSI (s) (20:28) [09:52:43:015]: User policy value 'AlwaysInstallElevated' is 0
MSI (s) (20:28) [09:52:43:015]: MSI_LUA: UAC support is not enabled; therefore no elevation thru prompting is possible
MSI (s) (20:28) [09:52:43:015]: Note: 1: 3 
MSI (s) (20:28) [09:52:43:015]: SECUREREPAIR: SecureRepair Failed. Error code: 3F56634B8
Action ended 09:52:43: RegisterProduct. Return value 2.
```

Also, I am seeing several lines like:

```
MSI (s) (20:F0) [09:52:33:077]: MSI_LUA: Credential prompt disabled due to LUA policy settings
```

My first thought was that the MSI needs elevation but a GPO has disabled the prompt and the installation fails as seen in point 2 of:

[Configure UAC settings via policy](http://blogs.technet.com/b/asiasupp/archive/2007/02/08/configure-uac-settings-via-policy.aspx)

But the Domain administrators swear by ... that there is not such policy in their GPOs and I cannot access it to check.

Then, my second thought takes me to:

[Infamous KB2918614](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2918614)

But non of the described errors matches mine: `SECUREREPAIR: SecureRepair Failed. Error code: 3F56634B8`

All I have is the log to understand this problem and have no access to the machines.

The MSI runs well in other Domains and I have run out of ideas. Any lead is much appreciated as I have already been a couple of weeks reading things and can't find any. I am still suspicious of GPO but have to take the word...

Comment: Is it possible to share your entire log file somewhere so that we could take a deeper look at it?

Comment: @KiranHegde, Sure! it is quite a large file (5624 lines). Shall I post it here?

Comment: Can you upload it to drop box so that i could download it?

Comment: @KiranHegde, Please, get it from [link](http://www.aznarepse.com/loginstallanonymous.txt). Note that this is the log for the install by a normal user in the domain. The msi has been advertised successfully before by an administrator in the machine as per [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa369519.aspx). This works in any other domain.